# Vue JS parsing query params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I can read query values using

```
{{$route.query.id}}
```

But I want to pass that id to another route.
Who could I achieve this?
I tried this and It didn't worked.

```
startExam(){
      this.$router.push({
        path:'/QuestionPaper',
        query:{
          id:$route.query.id
        }
      });
    }
```

This is my full code. I want to pass it to the question paper route.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <button type="button" name="button" class="btn" @click="startExam">Start Exam</button>
    <h2>You have 1 hr 30 min to complete</h2>
    <h2>PaperID : {{$route.query.id}}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    startExam(){
      this.$router.push({
        path:'/QuestionPaper',
        query:{
          id:$route.query.id
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Inside the script section, use `this` to access local properties: `this.$route.query.id`

Comment: Thank! It works! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in front of $route

```
query:{
      id:this.$route.query.id
    }
```

Comment: it.s my pleasure  ：）